# WebStorm, close the error code not written colon

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Using WebStorm.

I do not want to write semicolon `;` at the end, how to turn off the error ?

Comment: do you mean this ( ; ) colon?

Comment: Can you show us the code and describe what exactly is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File > Settings > Editor > Inspections > JavaScript > Code Style Issues > uncheck 'Unterminated statement'.

You'll have to restart WebStorm.

You can also do this in 'Default Settings' so this applies to any future projects.